# Delay in onReceive code of BroadcastReceiver being executed

Tags: java, android, networking, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I am using a BroadcastReceiver to monitor changes in network state, however there is a delay before the code in my onReceive is executed and i need it to be instant. Any ideas as to what I should do?

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: You do not control the timing of when that broadcast is sent. You do not control the order in which Android will deliver the broadcast. Hence, you have no way of getting this to be "instant", for however you are defining that.

Answer (score 0):

First check in your broadcast class you are not doing a heavy process which could delay your broadcast, dont forget to use an asynctask or thread in case of doing heavy work, second you could try to put the priority flag on the broadcast receiver in the manifest and put the value of 999 as maximum, depending the broadcast this could improve the performance.

android:priority="999"